# Simple question about superposition-theorem

Tags: current

Which one is correct? (first one is my solution, second one is how my teacher solved it in class as an example when he was teaching superposition theorem).

Red rectangles are where the difference is.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your calculation the problem is with \$V_2\$. You have a voltage divider, so it should be

$$V_2=3\cdot\frac{9}{6+9}=\frac{9}{5}$$

So the total voltage \$V\$ becomes

$$V=V_1+V_2=\frac{36+9}{5}=9$$

And \$i_x\$ is given by

$$i_x=\frac{V}{9}=1$$

as it should be.

**EDIT:**

To make it even a bit clearer: you can also directly compute the contributions of the two sources to the current \$i_x\$. Let \$i_{x,1}\$ be the contribution of the current source:

$$i_{x,1}=2\cdot\frac{6\cdot 9}{6+9}\cdot 9=\frac{12}{15}$$

The contribution of the voltage source is \$i_{x,2}\$:

$$i_{x,2}=\frac{3}{6+9}=\frac{3}{15}$$

So the total current is

$$i_x=i_{x,1}+i_{x,2}=\frac{12}{15}+\frac{3}{15}=\frac{15}{15}=1$$

which is of course the same result as obtained above.

Comment: thanks, but how come in my solution V2 = 9/5 and in my teacher's solution V2 = 3 ?

Comment: @kptlronyttcn: Your teacher's 'solution' is not using superposition properly. You can see this because he uses \$i_x\$ when only considering the current source, whereas \$i_x\$ should be the superposition of the currents caused by the current source AND by the voltage source.